# Problem when merging, please help

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, merge

When I try to merge an image with an adjustment layer, the whole image change.

Without merging:
[image]

After merging the image with the adjustment layer:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you merge? If you select the adjustment layer and do Command/Control E to merge down, that should work.

Comment: That's how I do it, it always work fine but with this image not and I don't know why

Comment: **Always** view at 100% before merging. I suspect the reason you notice it changing is because your view is at 33%. So, there's some "preview scale" antialiasing there before the merge.. not after. At 100% you may not see *any* change.

Comment: Exactly,that was the problem. Thank you so much. But now I have other problem, how can I reduce the white noise of the image? It doesn't work with curves

Comment: You need to ask that as a new question (unless you can find a similar question on the site). There are different ways of doing this, but it will decrease the quality of the image. It's better to apply less noise in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

**Always** view at 100% before merging.

I suspect the reason you notice it changing is because your *view is at 33%*. So, there's some "preview scale" antialiasing there before the merge.... not after. At 100% you may not see any change.