# Re Photoshop image adjustment

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Whenever I try to implement an image change, I see the effect in preview but then the appearance of the image goes back to what it was. The change doesn't take effect. For example, I may increase the contrast with the curve adjustment tool but the change doesn't take effect.

Comment: Hello, we will need more information for us to answer this question. Can you take a screenshot of your layers panel? This could be a computer spec issue. If you make a change, save the file, then open the file, was the change made?

Comment: **Be certain you are viewing the image at 100% when making adjustments.** Adjustments may be minute and zooming in or out on the image may not make changes immediately noticeable due to anti-aliasing for the screen. - Viewing the image at 100% allow you to *actually see* what is taking place and removed the necessary screen anti-aliasing caused by zooming. Same issue [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130743/problem-when-merging-please-help).